# How to hide mesh associated with bone?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, objects, bones

I have a singular object and it is rigged with an armature:

[image]

but when I hide the forearm bone it doesn't hide the object mesh with it like it should:

[image]

where as this should what it look like after hiding the bone:

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: this is not how it is intended to work. And the question is: how should blender react if just parts of a mesh are used? and "normally" there is weight painting...so values from 0 to 1 are used for the mesh. Until which value Blender should hide the mesh? The only case is would make sense (for me) is if you have parented the mesh to bone.

Comment: @Chris I was thinking there was a customizable solution for what weight values should be hidden on hiding the bone, also is it possible to parent specific mesh segments to specific bones so that when u hide the bone the mesh gets hidden too?

Comment: you can't automatically hide the mesh when you hide the bone, you can just select the vertex group that is controlled by the bone and hide it with H

Comment: does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267162/how-to-connect-visibility-of-object-with-visibility-of-bone

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie look again I'm the one who asked that question xD

Comment: oh why are u asking the same question again? i had a hunch the same person asked it but i forgot to recheck the author XD but this might help to connect the question as duplicate.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I actually changed my approach, in this question there's a singular object connected to an armature & in the other question there are multiple objects connected to an armature so no they arn't the same question

Comment: fair enough. but still they are related so it can help others in the community.