# How to connect visibility of object with visibility of bone?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, drivers, visibility

I have an armature with multiple bones and a different object connected to each bone
[image]

when I hide my bone I want the object that is connected to it to hide as well

How do I achieve this? maybe via driver?

Comment: Is that for animation?

Comment: You can't except maybe with a script

Comment: you could do it with a driver, but then you have to adapt every driver manually...so really tedious

Comment: @Crantisz Yes it's for animation

Comment: @Chris all I want is the object to hide when bone hides, is that possible with a driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can, but it works "not fine":

[image]

right click on your bones "TV" -> copy as new driver

then right click on your objects "TV" and click "paste driver".

Then it "kind of" works.

The disadvantage: if you are in pose mode and press H you have to change to object/edit mode so that the object hides too....

To make it work in rendering as well,
copy paste the driver to the object camera Icon.

Comment: does it work for render viewport animation?

Comment: yes, if you change object/edit mode before rendering...as i said, it is pretty weird. I honestly don't know whether it is a bug...for me it looks like one.

Comment: I did as you did but when I hide the bone the object does not hide with it

Comment: after hiding, did you change  to object mode, edit mode, and object mode again?

Comment: if yes, pls provide blend file so i can check it out

Comment: aah you have to switch it like 2 time, yea it's weird but as long as it works in rendering it should be fine

Comment: i would assume if you keyframe your hide attribute and render an animation that it won't work because there is no change of object/edit mode while rendering animations....

Comment: yep it doesn't render but when I play the animation it works perfectly, any solution for that?

Comment: great! then my answer helps you so pls click on the checkmark left to my answer ;)

Comment: ah ha! I found a way to make it work in rendering as well! instead of copy pasting from bone TV icon copy paste the driver to the object camera Icon, add that to your answer and I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 2):

Good to know the more simple answer works, but I also wrote a custom operator to accomplish this task, It works in pose and edit_armature mode, but does not yet have an "unhide" method that works in reverse. I will leave this to you to reverse engineer how to accomplish.

It only works if the object is parented to the bone via *Parent> Bone* not *Parent > With Automatic Weights* or any of the other ones, but I figure you know this.

You can just run the script in the text editor, call it from the search menu and then set a hotkey for it there.

```
import bpy


class ToggleHiddenObjectBone(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.toggle_hide_bone_object"
    bl_label = "Toggle Hide on Parented Bones and Objects"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_bone is not None and context.mode in {"POSE", "EDIT_ARMATURE"}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.mode = context.mode
        self.parent_bones = dict(zip(
            [obj.parent_bone for obj in bpy.data.objects],
            [obj.name for obj in bpy.data.objects],
            ))
        
        self.bone = context.active_bone
        self.armature = [
            arm for arm in bpy.data.armatures[:] 
            if self.bone.basename in 
            [bone.basename for bone in arm.bones[:]
            ]][0]
        try:
            self.obj_name = self.parent_bones[self.bone.name]
        except KeyError:
            self.report({"INFO"}, "Bone not found in object parent bones, make sure you set 'Parent > Bone'")
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        if not self.obj_name:
            self.report({"INFO"}, "Active bone has no child object.")
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        else:
            return self.execute(context)
            
        
    def execute(self, context):
        obj = bpy.data.objects[self.obj_name]
        if self.mode == "POSE":
            bpy.ops.pose.hide()
        else:
            bpy.ops.armature.hide()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        obj.select_set(True)        
        bpy.ops.object.hide_view_set() 
        context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[self.armature.name]
        print(context.view_layer.objects.active)
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=self.mode)
        except TypeError:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    
        return {'FINISHED'}




# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToggleHiddenObjectBone)
   
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToggleHiddenObjectBone)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39129/131649) answer

you can achieve the same process via scripting, just in case you want to automate the process

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

def add_hide_driver(
        source, target, prop, dataPath,
        index = -1, negative = False, func = ''):

    if index != -1:
        d = source.driver_add( prop, index ).driver
    else:
        d = source.driver_add( prop ).driver

    v = d.variables.new()
    v.name                 = prop
    v.targets[0].id_type   = 'ARMATURE'
    v.targets[0].id        = target
    v.targets[0].data_path = dataPath

    d.expression = func + "(" + v.name + ")" if func else v.name
    d.expression = d.expression if not negative else "-1 * " + d.expression

armature=bpy.data.armatures["Armature"]

for bone in armature.bones:
    target_obj=bpy.data.objects[bone.name]
    add_hide_driver(target_obj,bone.id_data, 'hide_render', 'bones["'+bone.name+'"].hide')
```

This will achieve the same thing as copying driver from TV to Camera
as mentioned in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267168/131649) answer